# JavaScript call constructor with parameters from method

Tags: javascript, class

I wrote a minimal JavaScript class that accepts 2 parameters for the constructor as follows:

```
class myClass {
    constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  startProcess() {
    // call other functions that use this.name and this.age
  }
}

var init = new myClass('John', 29);
init.startProcess();
```

Is there a way to remove the `John` and `29` parameters when initializing `myClass` and add them to `init.startProcess`? I still want those parameters to be accessible from other functions.

Basically, I want to do this and keep the same functionality.

```
var init = new myClass();
init.startProcess('John', 29);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the constructor and move the initialization code to `startProcess`:

```js
class myClass {
  startProcess(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const init = new myClass();
init.startProcess('John', 29);

console.log(init);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it to the function `startProcess` and emit them from the `constructor`. This will let you to initialize the values in two forms. If you don't pass anything to the `constructor`, it will create variables but set the values to `undefined`. Also because here is a code duplicating, you can add this part into the `private function`

```js
class myClass {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this._init(name, age);
  }

  startProcess(name, age) {
    this._init(name, age);
    // Other logics
  }
  
  _init(name, age) {
     this.name = name;
     this.age = age;
  }
}

const init = new myClass();
init.startProcess('John', 29);

console.log(init);
```